# Goでinvalid memory address or nil pointer dereferenceが発生する

Tags: go

下記のコードを実行すると
`panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`が発生します。
これは、Insert()が返す*NodeのLeftがnilになっているからだと思うのですが、
Node.Leftがnilにならないようにするにはどうすればいいのでしょうか?

```
package main

type Node struct {
    Value               int
    Left, Right, Parent *Node
}

func (n *Node) Insert(num int) *Node {

    if num > n.Value {
        n.Left.Value = num
        n.Left.Parent = n
    } else if num < n.Value {
        n.Right.Value = num
        n.Right.Parent = n
    }
    return n
}

func main() {
    root := &Node{Value: 1264523}
    root.Insert(222222)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`main` 関数で `root` 変数に `Node` 型構造体(へのポインタ)を代入しているのと同じ様に、`n.Left` と `n.Right` にも `Node` 型構造体を割り当ててあげれば良いのではないでしょうか。

```golang
func (n *Node) Insert(num int) *Node {
    if num > n.Value {
        n.Left = &Node{Value: num, Parent: n}
    } else if num < n.Value {
        n.Right = &Node{Value: num, Parent: n}
    }
    return n
}
```

ただ、新たに `Node` 型構造体を挿入する前に既に `n.Left` ノードや `n.Right` ノードが存在する場合には、「ノードの付け替え」を行う必要がある様に思われます。